# Issues in ADC of PIC16F887 reading LM35 temperature value is frequently varying

Tags: embedded

I have connected the LM35 temperature sensor in analog channel of AN1 then transmitting the temperature through serial RS232 in PIC16F887. I have read the temperature value but the value is frequently varying as 31 and 32, also when touch the LM35 temperature is varying very fast as 32, 33 and etc.  How to control the constant temperature value. Here is my code, Please any one help me.

```
#include <htc.h>
void main(void)
{
     TRISA1 = 1;
     ANS1 = 1;
     OSCCON = 0x78; // OSCILLATOR CONTROL REGISTER 
     TXSTA = 0x26;
     RCSTA = 0x90;
     SPBRG = 10;
     ADCON1 = 0x80;
     unsigned int current_temp, initial_temp = temperature();
     transmit_char(initial_temp);
     flag = 0;

     while (1)
     {
          current_temp = temperature();
          if((current_temp == (initial_temp + 1)) || (current_temp == (initial_temp - 1)))
          {
               flag = 1;
          }
          if(flag == 1)
          {
               flag = 0;
               transmit_char(current_temp);
               initial_temp = current_temp;
          }
     }
}

int temperature(void)
{ 
     ADCON0 = 0xC5;
     GODONE = 1;
     while(GODONE);
     int temp;
     temp = (ADRESH << 8) + ADRESL;
     temp = temp/2;
     return temp;
}
```

Comment: Some variation is normal. Read the datasheet and ensure your hardware is correct (noise, etc.). From the description, I don't see this is a software problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,
Collect ten adc data,
Remove min and max from that values.
sum the remaining 8 ADC values and divide the value by 8.
this should be continuous process, average for every ten samples
note: sampling and averaging should be ... 1 to 10 , next  2 to 11 and 3 to 12. at every reading you will get the adc value. sudden fluctuations also get filtered here.

Hope this helps.. good luck..